# How does function passed to scan(acc, value) works?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I understand how scan works , but I found example which I'm not able to understand... to scan we pass two values, accumulator and next emited value, so how below syntax works?

```
 private fetchCarsGridDataSubject = new Subject<GridDataRequestDto>();
 private fetchCarsGridDataAction$ = this.fetchCarsGridDataSubject.asObservable().pipe(
    switchMap((gridDataRequestDto: GridDataRequestDto) => {
      return this.fetchCarsForGrid(gridDataRequestDto);
    }),
    map(data => (vm: CarsGridManagementVM) => ({
      ...vm,
    }))
  );

  vm$ = merge(this.fetchCarsGridDataAction$).pipe(
    scan(
      (prevVm: CarsGridManagementVM, mutationFn: (vm: CarsGridManagementVM) => CarsGridManagementVM) =>
        mutationFn(prevVm) as CarsGridManagementVM
    )
  );
```

I don' understand this mutationFn, this method is never declared in code, it is only used here in this case. How this scan function will work with mutationFn in that case? Why we don't have to declare mutationFn body with logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this method is never declared in code

Well, it sorta is!  The `fetchCarsGridDataAction$` observable is mapping the emitted data into a function.  So the function is declared witin the `map`:

```js
    map(data => (vm: CarsGridManagementVM) => ({
      ...vm,
    }))
```

Therefore, inside your `scan`, the "next emitted value" is the function emitted by `fetchCarsGridDataAction$`

Answer (score 1):

It is declared in code, in the pipe of fetchCarsGridDataAction$ in the map function the data is mapped to a function. This means that fetchCarsGridDataAction$ always emits a function. It is garbage code as the scan is never going to get a prevVm that is a CarsGridManagementVM, it will be a function that has been cast to a CarsGridManagementVM. The data object got lost in the map to a function and this code is a confused load of useless garbage.

Comment: So what is best way to do it in Your opinion?

Comment: Get rid of the map function so that fetchCarsGridDataAction$ actually emits the correct data, then in the scan do the spread operator each iteration so that the accumulator gets the new items emitted and adds them to the existing items.

Comment: hmm I will consider it, but in case when we have more merged observables all VM is updated correctly by this approach,